# How to loop through a multi-element JSON array in PHP?

Tags: php, json, loops, fpdf

I'm trying to loop through an JSON array in `PHP` and fill a `fpdf table`

My constructed string is valid JSON and looks like this:

```
[
 {"ap":"j4","la":"02.02.2012","tr":"30&nbsp;Tage","tra":"19.95EUR"}, 
 {"ap":"de","la":"27.09.2012","tr":"30&nbsp;Tage","tra":"19.95EUR"},
 ...
 ]
```

Which I'm setting as

```
if($rvar_apps != ""){
    $activeAppsJson = json_decode( $rvar_apps ,true);
}
```

And then I'm trying this, which blanks the page:

```
if( $activeAppsJson ){
    for($activeAppsJson as $item) {
        $pdf->Cell(25,8,$item['ap'],1,0);
        $pdf->Cell(25,8,$item['la'],1,0);
        $pdf->Cell(25,8,$item['tr'],1,0);
        $pdf->Cell(35,8,$item['tra'],1,1);

    }
}
```

Having never worked with php before... I need some help!

**Question**:
What's wrong with my loop and variables assignment. The assigment seems to work, but the blank page doesn't tell me what's wrong in my loop...

THANKS!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be **foreach** instead of **for**

```
foreach($activeAppsJson as $item) {
        $pdf->Cell(25,8,$item['ap'],1,0);
        $pdf->Cell(25,8,$item['la'],1,0);
        $pdf->Cell(25,8,$item['tr'],1,0);
        $pdf->Cell(35,8,$item['tra'],1,1);

    }
```

Comment: Ah. Thanks! No more errors, but `$activeAppsJson` seems empty (my pdf table is empty...). Am I decoding it correctly?

Comment: your json decoding is correct.it seems something else causing problem

Comment: nope. The server I'm renting runs php 5.2, but php manual says `json_decode`is available from php 5.2, so it should work, but returns NULL. I also tested magicquotes. That wasn't it, so I'm still searching.